# Questing regarding Wordpress DIVI layout settings

Tags: wordpress

I am using Divi standard theme (not 3rd party template). I created few Divi layouts , modules, sections using Divi Library and them imported them to different pages.

But now when I try to delete them from Divi > Divi library, they still show up on page. Tried to researched everywhere with no luck. How this forum can help.

Answer (score 0):

GO to the backend, edit page.. you'll find the modules/sections in the page .. delete manually.